# Re-showing dialog after dissmiss

Tags: java, android, dialog, kotlin, listener

how to re-show the same dialog after every dismiss?
My code(in Kotlin):

```
val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_dialog_main_activity))
val editText = EditText(this)
editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE
alertDialog.run {
    setView(editText)
    setOnDismissListener { TODO( "Re-show dialog" }
    setPositiveButton("Done", { dialogInterface, i ->
        run {
            toast(editText.text.toString())
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext).edit().putInt("phoneNumber", editText.text.toString().toInt()).commit()
            }
        })
    show()
}
```

Answers could be in Java too.

Comment: what about not allowing dismiss instead of reopening it? you can use show() I bet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this).apply {
    setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_dialog_main_activity))
    setView(editText)
    setOnDismissListener {
        if(/*TODO validate phone number*/)
        (it as AlertDialog).show()
    }
    setPositiveButton("Done", { dialogInterface, i ->
        toast(editText.text.toString())
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext).edit().putInt("phoneNumber", editText.text.toString().toInt()).commit()

    })
    show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be probably to recall the function displaying the dialog, like this:

```
    fun showDialog() {
        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_dialog_main_activity))
        val editText = EditText(this)
        editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE
        alertDialog.run {
            setView(editText)
            setOnDismissListener {
                 showDialog() // recall the function
            }
            setPositiveButton("Done", { dialogInterface, i -> {
                    toast(editText.text.toString())
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext).edit().putInt("phoneNumber", editText.text.toString().toInt()).commit()
                    }
                })
            show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: that crash app and in stacktrace, there is message saying that this view has already been shown